# $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of quadratic ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> Definition. A *quadratic ring* $R$ is a commutative ring with $(R,+) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ (The additive abelian group of $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2)$
>
> Lemma. If $R$ is a quadratic ring, then $R$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the form $\{1,t\}$ where $t \in R.$

What exactly is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis? Is this similar to a basis for a vector space?

Comment: Since $R$ is isomorphic as additive group to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, it is a free group, so it has a basis. What you need to show is that this basis can be chosen in that particular way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of an abelian group is a subset $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ such that every element can be expressed uniquely in terms of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. It is similar to a basis for a vector space, except that being a maximal linearly independent subset does not guarantee that the subset is a basis. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ the subset $\{(1,0),(0,2)\}$ is maximally linearly independent, but $(0,1)$ cannot be expressed in terms of elements of this subset.

Any free abelian group, such as $\mathbb{Z}^2$, has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis (this is actually an if and only if; if an abelian group has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis, then it is free abelian, isomorphic to the direct sum of some number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$). A key fact to note is that if $\{x,y\}$ is any basis and we have another subset $B=\{m_1x+n_1y,m_2x+n_2y\}$, then $B$ is a basis if and only if the matrix
$$M=\left(\begin{array}{ll}m_1&m_2\\n_1&n_2\end{array}\right)$$
is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$; this condition means that any equation of the form
$$M\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{w}$$
has a unique solution with integer components, meaning every $\mathbf{w}$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the columns of the matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. This just means that $\det(M)=\pm 1$.

Since $R\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ additively, $R$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis, say $\{a,b\}$. If $a=1$ or $b=1$, then we are done. Otherwise there exist integers $m,n$ such that
$$ma+nb=1$$
I claim that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Suppose instead that $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, say $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$. Then
$$1=d(m'a+n'b)$$
where $m'=m/d$, $n'=n/d$. Then we have
$$d^{-1}=m'a+n'b$$
Consider the elements $x=d^{-1}a$, $y=d^{-1}b$. The set $\{x,y\}$ must be a basis since in particular we may obtain $a$ and $b$ from $x$ and $y$, and if $x$ and $y$ were linearly dependent then so would $a$ and $b$ be. We may express our old basis as $a=dx$, $b=dy$. Using the characterization of bases in terms of another basis above, we must have that the determinant of the matrix
$$M=\left(\begin{array}{ll}d&0\\0&d\end{array}\right)$$
is $\pm 1$, which is clearly is not. This is a contradiction, hence we must have had that $d=1$.

To construct a basis that includes $1$, we need only find integers $p,q$ such that the determinant of the matrix with columns $m,n$ and $p,q$ is equal to $\pm 1$. Since $m,n$ are relatively prime, the equation
$$mq-np=1$$
has a solution, so such $p,q$ exist. Hence $\{1,pa+qb\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $R$, and we are done.